# White label apps and the App Store Review Guidelines

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval, white-labelling

I have a question about the App Store Review Guidelines concerning publishing white label apps.

The situation is the following: my company developed an app that is targeted at specific companies where only the employees of the company have login credentials to access the app. What we plan on doing is having multiple versions of this app but each version customized for each company (with their logos and colors) and again only the employees of each company are able to log into their company's apps.

My question is: does this concept violate any of the Apple Review Guidelines? More specifically, are the following items of the Apple Review Guidelines a problem?

2.11 - Apps that duplicate Apps already in the App Store may be rejected, particularly if there are many of them, such as fart, burp, flashlight, and Kama Sutra Apps

2.20 - Developers "spamming" the App Store with many versions of similar Apps will be removed from the iOS Developer Program

What do they mean by "similar apps"? Does our app fall into this category if only the employees of each company are able to log into each app? Has anyone had any experiences with this?

Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: I don't know the answer but I'm curious why App store distribution is being considered for this type of product.  Wouldn't it be a better match if your customers used enterprise distribution and had you build with their profiles?

Comment: I agree with @PhillipMills. And I'm pretty sure that Apple will not allow you to upload a bunch of these apps to appstore where most of the people won't be able to use these apps at all.

Comment: Maybe you must explore enterprise option for distribution and not upload in the "Normal" App Store

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can't submit the similar kind of apps with just changing the graphics & color combinations for the different companies.

**I have a better solution for this. Here are the points :**

- You should make a Web portal from where your application can be controlled. Basically there should be 1 common application which will be serving to different companies
- This will be served as a SAAS. Software as a service
- So where the multiple companies will get register to the portal can create the Ids for their employees, can choose the different themes. Now when their employees gets login to the system it will show the selected them color combinations to the application.
- It will be whole controlled by the Mobile Apis.

Hope this help to everyone.